# Mysql export view issue

Tags: mysql, database, view

While restoring the DB from it's backup we get data, stored procedure and views in it.

Data and stored procedure is properly backed up. But views table content are not backed up properly. When export with mysqldump it contain command like

```
CREATE VIEW AS SELECT 1 AS username, 1 as email, 1 as registered;
```

Refer below link but no solution found.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99426

Please help.

[image]

Comment: The image is unreadable...

Comment: Image contain error- Error loading schema content

Answer (score 0):

Use `dbusername`@`host` instead of `user`@`%`.
Example:
In my local, I used `user`@`localhost`